# Turtoise HG auto update local repo

Tags: mercurial, repository, local

I have a local repository and it's clone on my PC (windows). Is there any way I can perform an auto update on master repository after I push changes to it from the clone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a changegroup-hook in the master repository:

$EDITOR /master/repository/.hg/hgrc

```
[hooks]
changegroup = hg update
```

This will perform an update whenever something is pushed into the master repository.

Comment: I can't seem to find a file named hgrc. I have 2.9.0 version of TurtoiseHG.